# struts2 retrieve checkbox value in action class

Tags: java, struts2

I have a struts2 checkboxlist in a jsp page which looks like

```
s:checkboxlist label="Choose Customer :" name="cname" list="li" listKey="key" listValue="100"
```

When I run `checkBox.action` it displays customer names from the list. My question is when the user selects the first checkbox I want to retrieve `listvalue` which is "100" in the action class. In the action class I have `li.add("David"); li.add("Welker")` etc. with these customers having unique id's. So, I want to retrieve id's from the example id value 100 from `listvalue` in the action class. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

your list `li` should look like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> getLi(){
    li.put(yourId, "David");
    li.put(yourId, "Welker");
}
```

so you can make your `checklist` look like this:

```
<s:checklist label="Choose Customer :" name="cname" list="li" listKey="key" listValue="value"/>
```

so the checklist shows the names and give your the ID back.

Comment: Yes that is what I did and I can see checkboxes with two customer names david(id=100) and welker(id=200). If I select David for which , list value is 100 how should I get/retrieve that listvalue in action class. This is my question.

Comment: you mean you need both id and value, when you submit the form?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, the most easy way to do this is to put your `li` into session, then you can get the value at any time.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Here is my situation:                       I have 10 customers to be displayed in jsp page which I am retreiving from action class. These customers have different unique id's which I am putting in listValue="#{person.id}". So when customer selects checkbox 1 and checkbox 3 then in my action class I want to retriev listValues i.e 100 and 300 so that I can update him using their ids. All I need is retrieve listvalue in action class.